# Warning [x]: Possible date calculation spin for Schedule xx

Tags: sql-server

Just installed SQL server 2016. As I've been going through log files I discovered this warning in the SQL Agent log file:

```
Warning [x]: Possible date calculation spin for Schedule xx
```

Warning could be a number like 1, 2 or 3 and schedule seems to be a number referring to the schedule id you see when you open the "Manage Schedules" window (by right-clicking on the "jobs" folder in SSMS).

The schedule number for me has been 9, 22 or 24. When I look in "Manage Schedules" I clearly see a 24 (which for me is ASPState_Job_DeleteExpiredSessions) but no number 9 or 22.
The only information I can find online seems to refer to this as some sort of bug in SQL 7 or SQL 2000.

Anyone know why I see this warning and if I should be worried about it at all?

Comment: did u get this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f04bfb7d-be50-410a-beb1-52173eeb5419/possible-date-calculation-spin-for-schedule?forum=sqlsetupandupgrade ??